# How to list an Array and then list the array within that Array on click? Angular2 and Typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Attempting to build a click event where when the tierName is selected it will show the active tier and the colorNames within.

Here is my component:

```
    tiers: Tier[] = [
        {
          'tierName': "Primary",
          'description': "A set of colors that can be combined to make a useful range of colors.",
          'colors': [
            {colorName: 'Red', mix1: null, mix2: null, label: 'Primary'},
            {colorName: 'Blue', mix1: null, mix2: null, label: 'Primary'},
            {colorName: 'Yellow', mix1: null, mix2: null, label: 'Primary'}
          ]
        },
        {
          'tierName': "Secondary",
          'description': "A color made by mixing two primary colors",
          'colors': [
            {colorName: 'Purple', mix1: 'Blue', mix2: 'Red', label: 'Secondary'},
            {colorName: 'Orange', mix1: 'Red', mix2: 'Yellow', label: 'Secondary'},
            {colorName: 'Green', mix1: 'Blue', mix2: 'Yellow', label: 'Secondary'}
          ]
        },
        {
          'tierName': "Tertiary",
          'description': "A color made by mixing full saturation of one primary color with half saturation of another primary color and none of a third primary color.",
          'colors': [
            {colorName: 'Vermilion', mix1: 'Red', mix2: 'Orange', label: 'Tertiary'},
            {colorName: 'Amber', mix1: 'Orange', mix2: 'Yellow', label: 'Tertiary'},
            {colorName: 'Chartreuse', mix1: 'Yellow', mix2: 'Green', label: 'Tertiary'},
            {colorName: 'Teal', mix1: 'Green', mix2: 'Blue', label: 'Tertiary'},
            {colorName: 'Violet', mix1: 'Blue', mix2: 'Purple', label: 'Tertiary'},
            {colorName: 'Magenta', mix1: 'Purple', mix2: 'Red', label: 'Tertiary'}
          ]
        }
  ];
activeTier: tier;

selectTier(tier) {
this.activeTier = tier;
```

Using *ngIf and *ngFor to call it:

```
    <div *ngIf="tiers">
      <ul class="list-group tiers-list"> 
        <li class="list-group-item" 
          *ngFor="let tier of tiers"
          (click)="selectTier(tier)"
          [class.active]="tier === activeTier">
          {{ tierName }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I have tired the following component names:

```
tiers: Tier[] = {...};
tiers.tierlist = {...};
let tier: tier.list[] = {...};
```

I'm really stumped at this and still very new to Angular and Typescript. Any direction or input is much appreciated!

I understand that I was confusing objects and arrays, I have since corrected the code and am able to access the tierName however I'm still having difficulty accessing the colorName of colors.

Comment: Your data seems incorrect (it's a big object with other objects inside it, not an array), so you can't use `*ngFor`. Is it coming from `web service` or is it hardcoded?

Comment: @bardic I write here to say that I updated and undeleted my answer, so you won't be notified. But check my answer, there is complete answer to your question! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Since we got some new information on the actual data, the following solution should work, based on what you have provided:

First just iterate through the array of tiers, and have the click function that selects an active tier:

```
<div *ngIf="tiers">
  <ul class="list-group tiers-list">
    <li class="list-group-item"
      *ngFor="let tier of tiers"
      (click)="selectTier(tier)">
      {{ tier.tierName }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and you have your `selectTier`-method and the variable `activeTier`:

```
activeTier: tier;

selectTier(tier) {
   this.activeTier = tier;
}
```

Then just add a conditional div, that won't be displayed unless there is an active tier. Since we are dealing with an array we can iterate through the nested data just with `activeTier.colors` which will iterate the colors array in ngFor.

```
<div *ngIf="activeTier">
    <div *ngFor="let col of activeTier.colors">{{col.colorName}}</div>
</div>
```

And there ya go, all done :)

Comment: Thank you AJT, I realized that I was confusing arrays and objects and have corrected it to show it as tiers: Tier[] = [ {[ ]},{[ ]},{[ ]} ]. As you can see I have quite the nest going on and wish to access the object within the array that is within an object. Would I require a pipe for this?

Comment: thank you, that did do the trick! May I bug you one more time for direction on how to list each item as an individual div? In javascript I would use a foreach loop, in angular it seems like *ngFor and *ngIf are the only options but maybe I just haven't found the correct terminology?

Comment: Glad I could help! :) as to your comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "an individual div". Could you elaborate further please? :)

Comment: This is what I was trying to explain I wanted to accomplish:
                    <div class="front"">
                  <div class="frontDiv">
                  {{ color.colorName}}
                  </div>

Answer (score 1):

First of all what you call "list" is an Object, so *ngFor only works for an Array.

You have 2 Options:

1) Convert your "list" to a real list like:
   [{}, {}, {}] or easier yourArray: Object[] = Object.values(your object)

2) Create a pipe to convert an Object in a array like this:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class ObjectKeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Object, args: string[]) : any {
    if (!value || Object.keys(value).length === 0){
      return [];
    }
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

then use it like:

```
<div *ngIf="tiers">
 <ul class="list-group tiers-list"> 
    <li class="list-group-item" 
      *ngFor="let tier of (tiers | keys)"
      (click)="selectTier(tier.value)"
      [class.active]="tier.value === activeTier">
      {{ tier.value.tierName }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```